Neutralizing after paint stripper
I used this 15 min paint stripper to remove old paint from this old window safety bars. I plan to do one coat of mineral spirits as per the instructions on the container, to clean the residue. However, the container specifies nothing about neutralizing. I have worked with some other strippers that did need to be neutralized specifically, with something like baking soda solution. Should I neutralize this stripping job with the same solution?


If the container does not mention neutralizing, why do you think it is needed?  You should follow the instructions that are with the product.


I plan to do one coat of mineral spirits as per the instructions on the container.

Mineral spirits  ( white spirit, mineral turpentine, Stoddard solvent, ... ) is not a coating; is a solvent.  Be sure to follow the instructions exactly.
I suspect that the instructions say to wipe with mineral spirits meaning you dampen a rag with mineral spirits and use that to wipe off any remaining stripper residue.
This wiping will clean off any remaining stripper,

i used a wrong term
